# Saving a container i Openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I know that in docker there is the command "docker commit" that take a running container and give the image. 
Is there an equivalent command in Openshift?

Comment: Have a look at this blog post https://blog.openshift.com/pushing-application-images-to-an-external-registry/ and then check the OpenShift documentation for more details on this mechanism.

Comment: thank you.
So, could I assume that is not possible to save some change that i make in a container at all?

Comment: Please don't change the question so it means something entirely different to what you originally had. If you had a followup question you should create a new question. And no, you cannot create a new image from the state of a container at the point it exited. Perhaps in your new question explain what you want to do, rather than ask how to do what you think is the solution to whatever problem you have. If you state the original problem then people can guide you to the correct solution.